# contour plot with four 1D arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, contourf

I have four 1d arrays, 2 arrays show x and y axis data, and the other two arrays represent the f(x) and f(y) values with respect the x and y axis. I want to plot a contour plot from these four arrays. The following code is running perfectly but the plot is not correct. I think, the error is in "Z" values. I can convert the "Z" into a perfect 2D array for the contour plot. I want to know is there any better way other than "np.outer" to convert two fx and fy arrays into "Z" for contourplot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([1,2,3])

fx = np.array([2,4,6])
fy = np.array([2,4,6])

Z = np.outer(fx,fy)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

I want a contour plot from four 1d arrays.

Comment: If `np.outer` isn't the correct operation for combining fx and fy to create Z, how would you describe the correct operation?